# Maven - How to organize projects/modules?

Tags: java, maven

I am developing a Windows Service that uses TCP/IP to communicate with their clients.

So i create a project for the service using Maven. Now i need to create a client to comunicate with this service. Is it better to create another project or a module? Or create it inside the Windows Service project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For development purposes it easier to create another module. First, its easy to view both client and server code in the IDE without having to close and open projects. Second, common code can be placed in another module, which makes easier to code and debug.

Comment: I create one super project, with <packaging>pom</packaging>. Then create two children modules, one is the Server and other is the client. For now, it's working!